# Start a workflow from a custom button/action on a list item in SharePoint 2010 (all with Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, code-behind, custom-action

I'm sorry for asking a double question, but I'm messed up with finding no solution - or a missing understanding of answers.

My problem is like descrided:

I have some self constructed custom ribbons with buttons. And I like to start a workflow if I click on designed button.

Okay, more about settings:

It is a generic list, means, my elemets.xml looks like that:

```
<CustomAction
  Id="MyCustomRibbonTab"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
  RegistrationId="100"
  RegistrationType="List">
  <CommandUIExtension>
    <CommandUIDefintions>
      <CommandUIDefinition
        Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
        <Tab Id="Ribbon.CustomTab" Sequence="501">
        ... (Scaling)
          <Groups Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Groups">
            <Group 
              Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.GroupOne" 
              Sequence="52">
              <Controls Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.GroupOne.Controls">
                <Button
                  Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.GroupOne.ButtonOne"
                  Command="CustomTab.ButtonOneCommand"
                  Sequence="11">
              </Controls>
            </Group>
          </Groups>
        </Tab>
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIHandlers>
      <CommandUIHandler
        Command="CustomTab.ButtonOneCommand"
        CommandAction="javascript:alert('how start workflow here?');" />
        />
    </CommandUIHandlers>
  </CommandUIExtension>
  <!-- what about starting workflow here? How? -->
</CustomAction>
```

Hope it is clear what my XML-Post means. Okay, that works fine if I put CommandAction="javascript:alert('should start a workflow');" . I mean, this alert pops up and I can click okay, nothing else.

Now I have in same project my workflow designed. There are two types, one with initiation form in asp, the other without, both operating on selected item. I can start them while using the standard ribbon "Workflows" and then click them. Everything is fine so far.

But I want to start each workflow by clicking my button, not having more clicks as it is now. Thank you so far in helping me.

I'm very new on SharePoint. So please include in your answer stuff like "Add new ... Empty Element/ JavaScript File" or whatever is neccessary to get what I assume.

If you have more questions about my workflow design, I will answer asap.

Thank you very much,

danbruc

Note: Yes, I just hope that even my Elements.xml is fine. I took all from web. So if yuo have suggestions to redesign, I am open minded. Just blind in seeing the solution. 
 Additionally, I'm able to put this Tab inside ContextualTab of ListView, but then even javascript is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you read the documentation on [Customizing and Extending the SharePoint 2010 Server Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552606.aspx)?

It is very concise and shows you an important points concerning your problem:
You will need to do a postback to initiate the workflow via serverside code:

```
<CommandUIHandler Command="WebPartContextualTabs.OnPostback"
CommandAction="javascript:__doPostBack('StartMyWorkflowPostBack','');" />
```

Now what to put in `StartMyWorkflowPostBack` to start your workflow? There are several resources for this and you will find plenty more via Google:

- [Start Workflow From c# Code](http://www.3kka.com/2009/12/start-workflow-from-c-code.html)
- [Creating new instance of SharePoint workflow through C# code.](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-new-instance-of-workflow.html)
- [HOWTO: Start a SharePoint 2010 Workflow Programatically](http://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2010/07/15/howto-start-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-programatically/)

Let me explain in short: You did not tell us what kind of workflow. A list based workflow or a site workflow, start methods differ for these. Taking the list workflow as an example you will need to just start the workflow like so:

```
SPWorkflowProperties.Site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(listItem, associationTemplate, initData);
```

But as you can see you will need a lot of stuff for this: The `SPListItem`, the `SPWorkflowAssociationTemplate` as well as some initiation data.

Comment: Dear moontear,
thank you very much for your fast answer. I will look inside your links, they sound very useful.
And it looks like I was not able to ask the right questions for google. Because I found tons of walkthroughs for a workflow, again tons for custom actions but none combined.

Referring to your questions:
a) all workflows are for a specific list
b) some have an initiation form, others don't

Thank you, I will post after understanding your links

Comment: What you're trying to do is not easy, but achievable. Understand the Postback example on MSDN for your custom action, and just call a `StartWorkflow` in code behind - that's basically the process :-)

Comment: ATM I was able to start workflows from another one while all were deployed by me. That is great and for later use. The postback-stuff will be next but now I'm out of office and wish you a happy weekend with enjoyable moments. (not everybody belongs to christmas).

Comment: I actually found out that you can directly start a workflow via the JS object model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550060.aspx pretty interesting and wouldn't involve code behind :-)

Comment: Hi moontear, thank you very much for your researching effort. Sorry for not looking again last days. But wish you a happy new year. I will try out your suggestion in next time and give feedback.